# Using HTML5 validation feature to check for existing username

Tags: php, forms, html, validation

I'm creating a registration form and I would like to check if the user already exist using PHP and HTML5 validation.

So somehow I would like to send the username that was typed in to a PHP function and write error message with `setCustomValidity()` in JavaScript (HTML5)

Can anyone offer me any advice to achieve this?

Comment: I do not understand your question - please clarify!

Comment: are you tell to check in a db an user, thing that could be done in php?

Comment: You don't just can, you should.(It depends on which types of validation you need). HTML is a client-side language, PHP is a server-side language.

Comment: You need both sides to do proper validation. What you want to achieve here?

Comment: Checking whether a username already exists is not the same thing as "HTML validation". The former is "data validation" or "input validation" - and the latter is a name for checking whether your static/generated HTML(5) is semantically correct.

Comment: @halfer: HTML5 has built-in validation of input fields, to check if it's actually a number, an email address, etc. But that cannot check if a username exists.

Comment: @animuson - thanks, I didn't know HTML5 offered such a facility - must look at that sometime! Yes, that would be client-side only, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this automatically, if that's what you're asking. You'll need to provide validation on the server-side, too. HTML5 is client-side. And even if it *did* send usable validation parameters somehow, those could be falsified.

As for checking if a user already exists, this can't be done with HTML5. What you *can* do is client-side validation with [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

Comment: It depends how he defines "validations".
There are few validations you can do with JS.

Answer (score 0):

To check username is already exist in DB, we need to write server side script. To handle this type of validation we can do using javascript ajax functionality. Using HTML5 you can't validate username or any value with DB.